# Now Outlook and Outlook.com add margins to paragraphs inside cells! How to avoid?

Tags: css, html-email, outlook-2007, newsletter, hotmail

Today I was testing emails and email signatures with outlook.com and while I'm sending from Outlook 2007 I found both add the usual unnecessary paragraph with msoNormal class around my content in the table cells.

That give stupid 13.5pt line-height and other paragraph 14pt bottom margin.

I did managed the line-height issue but I still receive it on outlook.com with that bottom margin (14pt) with spans inside or only text .. with styling or not while it's fine on all other mail providers / clients.

## HTML for test

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
   <tr>
      <td width="80" style="height:13px;">data</td>
      <td style="height:13px;">data</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width="80" style="height:13px;">data</td>
      <td style="height:13px;">data</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width="80" style="height:13px;">data</td>
      <td style="height:13px;">data</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

## Screenshots

Here after a couple of screenshots for the problem with and without styling:

[image: With spans and links inside and style for the cells]

**Without any type of styling**

[image: Without any type of styling]

Here is how it should be and how it appears on Gmail while it was sent also from Outlook 2007 
[image]

Comment: You could avoid all the headaches caused by making HTML emails look good (believe me I know ;) ) using something link Ink: http://zurb.com/ink/

Comment: Should I tell all my clients to use it in their daily tasks? should they leave their Outlook and signature problems? this can't help but thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to avoid the Outlook msoNormal gaps on forwarding to Gmail. Here is an [interesting article](http://commadot.com/gmail-and-p-msonormal/) on the topic.

There are ways to limit it's effect though. The gap created between tables is bigger than the gap created between table rows. As you have rows, you are already experiencing the lesser.

The easiest fix would be simply combining your rows into one row with `<br>`'s separating the lines of text.

Example:

```
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="100">
address<br>
phone<br>
fax
    </td>
    <td width="500">
: your address<br>
: your phone<br>
: your fax
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This may also have something to do with the min `<td>` height. Outlook has a minimum height of 19px, so anything smaller can create unwanted vertical space. There are some line-height hacks, you can try to work around this also.

Comment: John .. Thank you .. I was using spans for address labels and converted it to table to justify the labels since Ouylook doesn't deal with inline-block. separating with <br> will make me back to zero and use spans again.

Comment: actually I received the original message (not the forwarding) fine on Gmail and was strange that it's Hotmail/Microsoft which has the problem.

Comment: Outlook is the cause. It edits your code and adds its own formatting to it. This is passed on to any other email client once forwarded out of Outlook. I updated the answer, put an example in there. Does that solve your justification issue?

Comment: thankful for your effort. I know what Outlook adds and how it acts. meant Gmail doesn't remove the extra classes but still can deal with it while outlook.com doesn't. may you please look to the third attached image which captured as "Here is how it should be and how it appears on Gmail " .. this is how I want my output, otherwise i have many solutions

Comment: My code example should work on all clients including Outlook.com. It will not create any unwanted padding in between the rows of text. Just put in your correct text, font styling and hyperlinks and it is the exact same as your desired result.

Comment: Dear I know you did great simple code that works fine and I'm sure. please look to the my table address labels and the ":" after each. I need to justify things and that needs blocks that's all. here is the screenshot if you didn't know what I meant before http://i.stack.imgur.com/q5DGV.png

Comment: Then just put your ":" in the other column. I updated my code to show this.

Comment: I think it still could be used statically like here http://jsfiddle.net/LEuKc/ with few problems in long text if dynamically entered. it could work anyway .. thanks

Comment: That is the downfall of this all in one `<td>` solution. You could add a column in the middle for the ":" to prevent the second row of text lining up below the ":". But for the rows vertically misaligning with their labels, you would have to go back to your original code row by row code, and `valign="top"` all the `<td>`'s

Comment: Sure that wont help this will only add another challenges since we will need to add <br> after each http://jsfiddle.net/LEuKc/1/ .. anyway thank you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y7UmK/ This is the best way to do it in html email. It is basically what you had however...

Comment: Yeh, so table TDs is the only way we have and works to get equal labels instead of inline-block spans and works with Outlook .. right?